# Read in characters from txt and knit with page break

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am generating a list of objects in Rmarkdown and put them into a txt file, and then read content from the file to knit a PDF. However, currently I can only insert `\n` but not page break. I want to generate a PDF with 5 pages if there are 5 tables (1 table/page), I tried `\pagebreak` but doesn't work. Any suggestions?

The following is my code. Suppose you can use and edit it directly in a markdown file.

````
---
title: "My_RMarkdown_Document"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, comment = NA)
```

```{r txt file, include=FALSE}
if(file.exists('./output.txt'))
  file.remove('./output.txt')
obj_filepath <- file.path('./output.txt')
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
for(f in 1:5){
  context <- "I am generating a list of tables in Rmarkdown \nand put them into a txt file, \nand then read content from the file to knit a PDF. \nHowever, \ncurrently I can only insert \\\\n but not page break. \nI want to generate a PDF with 5 pages if there are 5 tables (1 table/page), \nI tried \\\\pagebreak but doesn't work. \nAny suggestions? \nMany thanks."

  cat(toString(context), file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat(toString('\n'), file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat(toString('\n'), file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
}
cat(toString('\n'), file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
tools::md5sum(normalizePath(obj_filepath))
```

```{r output, include=TRUE}
str_tbl <- readLines(obj_filepath)
cat(str_tbl, sep = '\n')
```
````

Comment: Can you rewrite this example to avoid using the 'rtables' package? Since it's not on CRAN, people who are trying to recreate this example would be reluctant to install it.

Comment: @bschneidr thanks I have edited it.

Comment: Thank you- this is a good reproducible example by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two things that need to be done. First, in order to include verbatim LaTeX code that will be properly interpreted by RMarkdown, you need to set the knitr chunk option `results='asis'`.

````
```{r output, include=TRUE, results='asis'}
str_tbl <- readLines(obj_filepath)
cat(str_tbl, sep = '\n')
```
````

Once you've done that, the string `"\\pagebreak"` will be properly interpreted as a LaTeX command. So this following code will successfully create a pagebreak.

```
  cat('\n', file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat('\n', file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat("\\pagebreak", file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat('\n', file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
```

Here's the full document:

````
---
title: "My_RMarkdown_Document"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, comment = NA)
```

```{r txt file, include=FALSE}
if(file.exists('./output.txt'))
  file.remove('./output.txt')
obj_filepath <- file.path('./output.txt')
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
for(f in 1:5){
  context <- "I am generating a list of tables in Rmarkdown \nand put them into a txt file, \nand then read content from the file to knit a PDF. \nHowever, \ncurrently I can only insert \\\\n but not page break. \nI want to generate a PDF with 5 pages if there are 5 tables (1 table/page), \nI tried \\\\pagebreak but doesn't work. \nAny suggestions? \nMany thanks."

  cat(context, file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat("\n", file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat("\n", file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat("\\pagebreak", file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
  cat("\n", file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
}
cat('\n', file = obj_filepath, append = TRUE)
tools::md5sum(normalizePath(obj_filepath))
```

```{r output, include=TRUE, results='asis'}
str_tbl <- readLines(obj_filepath)
cat(str_tbl, sep = '\n')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Does changing `\f` in place of one of your `\n` work for creating a pagebreak?
It appears to work on my system